# New images always predict one label

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I have trained a SVM for image classification using RGB histogram as features and a couple of other ones.

These are my feature and label sizes:

```
STATUS] feature vector size (11244, 525)
[STATUS] training Labels (11244,)
[STATUS] training labels encoded...
[STATUS] feature vector normalized...
[STATUS] target labels: [0 0 0 ... 1 1 1]
[STATUS] target labels shape: (11244,)
```

I am using sklearn's **train_test_split** with ratio of 0.15 for test.

Following is the classification report(100% recall and precision on test). This is weird!!

```
Tuning hyper-parameters for precision

Best parameters set found on development set:

{'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}

Grid scores on development set:

0.991 (+/-0.005) for {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.852 (+/-0.003) for {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.993 (+/-0.003) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.991 (+/-0.005) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.999 (+/-0.002) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.993 (+/-0.003) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
1.000 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.999 (+/-0.002) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
1.000 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}
1.000 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 10, 'kernel': 'linear'}
1.000 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 100, 'kernel': 'linear'}
1.000 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 1000, 'kernel': 'linear'}

Detailed classification report:

The model is trained on the full development set.
The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.

precision recall f1-score support

0 1.00 1.00 1.00 574
1 1.00 1.00 1.00 1113

micro avg 1.00 1.00 1.00 1687
macro avg 1.00 1.00 1.00 1687
weighted avg 1.00 1.00 1.00 1687

# Tuning hyper-parameters for recall

Best parameters set found on development set:

{'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}

Grid scores on development set:

0.986 (+/-0.006) for {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.633 (+/-0.009) for {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.988 (+/-0.005) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.986 (+/-0.006) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.998 (+/-0.003) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.988 (+/-0.005) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
1.000 (+/-0.001) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.998 (+/-0.003) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
1.000 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 1, 'kernel': 'linear'}
1.000 (+/-0.001) for {'C': 10, 'kernel': 'linear'}
1.000 (+/-0.001) for {'C': 100, 'kernel': 'linear'}
1.000 (+/-0.001) for {'C': 1000, 'kernel': 'linear'}

Detailed classification report:

The model is trained on the full development set.
The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.

precision recall f1-score support

0 1.00 1.00 1.00 574
1 1.00 1.00 1.00 1113

micro avg 1.00 1.00 1.00 1687
macro avg 1.00 1.00 1.00 1687
weighted avg 1.00 1.00 1.00 1687
```

BUT, on new images(sampled from same distribution), I am not getting even a single classification right. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Probably you have some data leakage, where information about the target leaks into your training and testset.

Comment: You need to show your code. Preferably as a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @jonnor sure, I will edit the question to share my code soon

Comment: Found the issue.It was related to StandardScaler function in sklearn which standardizes your input features. Not using standardization works perfectly for some reason.

Comment: Sounds like you did not standardize the inputs to your predictions in same way as while training. Use a pipeline, it makes managing that much easier. Lack of standardization usually reduces performance with SVM.

Comment: @jonnor I did standardize the inputs using StandardScaler and while inferring I used StandardScaler on each input image which should have been the right approach. But, apparently, it's not. Not using the standardization in either training or inference worked for me

Comment: Did you use the same instance? With fit_transform() during training and transform() during inference?

Comment: @jonnor yes, exactly the same! Maybe StandardScaler was standardized over a batch of images in training and hence that did not gel well with single inference image as it applies the batch mean and variance gathered from training set to inference image before prediction?

Comment: It should be OK, but batch sizes need to be fairly large, especially if you have lots of variation in the images. Maybe 100. And order of images should be randomized.